# How to use Substr with an F Expression

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, fuzzy-search

I'm trying to build a toolkit of `Func` classes built on the [`fuzzystrmatch`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/fuzzystrmatch.html) postgres extension.

For instance I have this wrapper which takes in an Expression and a search term and returns the levenshtein distance:

```py
class Levenshtein(Func):
    """This function calculates the Levenshtein distance between two strings:"""
    template = "%(function)s(%(expressions)s, '%(search_term)s')"
    function = "levenshtein"

    def __init__(self, expression, search_term, **extras):
        super(Levenshtein, self).__init__(
            expression,
            search_term=search_term,
            **extras
        )
```

Called like this, using an [`F Expression`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions):

```py
Author.objects.annotate(lev_dist=Levenshtein(F('name'),'JRR Tolkien').filter(lev_dist__lte=2)
```

However if the `'name'` field here is greater than 255 it throws an error:

> Both source and target can be any non-null string, with a maximum of 255 characters.

I can truncate the name when I annotate using `Substr`:

```py
Author.objects.annotate(clipped_name=Substr(F('name'),1,250))
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to place that logic inside the func, which I'm placing inside an `ExpressionWrapper` and setting the `output_field` as per [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#using-f-with-annotations):

```py
class Levenshtein(Func):
    """This function calculates the Levenshtein distance between two strings:"""
    template = "%(function)s(%(expressions)s, '%(search_term)s')"
    function = "levenshtein"

    def __init__(self, expression, search_term, **extras):
        super(Levenshtein, self).__init__(
            expression=ExpressionWrapper(Substr(expression, 1, 250), output_field=TextField()),
            search_term=search_term,
            **extras
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the docs don't make this super clear, just by experimenting it turns out the answer was to remove the extra definition of `expression` and pass in the `ExpressionWrapper` directly as the first argument:

```py
class Levenshtein(Func):
    """This function calculates the Levenshtein distance between two strings:"""
    template = "%(function)s(%(expressions)s, '%(search_term)s')"
    function = "levenshtein"

    def __init__(self, expression, search_term, **extras):
        super(Levenshtein, self).__init__(
            ExpressionWrapper(Substr(expression, 1, 250), output_field=TextField()),
            search_term=search_term,
            **extras
        )
```